# How do I have to arrange the remaining meeples after using the Ultra Bright Smile ability?

Tags: terror-in-meeple-city

The Super Secret ability Ultra Bright smile lets you eat escaped meeples then you can rearrange the remaining escaped meeples. My question regards rearranging the remaining meeples.

The first level of the escape board has 3 slots and the second has 5 slots. Lets say that after I eat, there are 6 meeples left. Do I have to fill the first row and put the remaining 3 meeples in the second row? Or could I put 2 meeples on the first row and 4 on the second?

Comment: Here is a link to the rules for peoples' reference: [Rampage* Rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/RAMPAGE_RULES_US.pdf)

*Now Terror in Meeple City

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [rulebook](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/RAMPAGE_RULES_US.pdf):

> **Ultra-Bright(TM) Smile**
>
> Instead of eating the Meeples in your Neighborhood, you can eat the Meeples currently
> on the Runaway board. Then reorganize the Meeples on the Runaway board without
> triggering any effects.

**For Side A:**

It isn't particularly clear but I think the key phrase  is "Then reorganize the Meeples on the Runaway board without triggering any effects." That heavily implies that you should follow the normal placement rules (and are safe from re-triggering previously triggered negative effects). The normal placement rules are:

> Place the Meeples on the Runaway board, starting with the top
> line.

So I would say that yes, you should "fill the first row and put the remaining 3 meeples in the second row".

**For Side B:**

It shouldn't matter as they are organised by colour and so the only consequence is a completed track may now be open to be re-triggered in future turns.

**For reference:**

Manuals in French, English and German are available at the [manufacturer's site](http://rprod.com/index.php?page=download-15).